# No module named 'adsk' problem - Python script for Autodesk Fusion 360

Tags: python-3.x, cad, fusion360

I want to draw 3D spheres using x,y,z coordinate. 
Then I am trying to use Python script for Autodesk Fusion 360(CAD).
However, the error has occurred as the image.
"No module named 'adsk' problem"

I tried to install the adsk module, but I cant intall.
Then I found that the adsk is in definition folder.
So I tried to run the file.
But I cant get result.

[image]

Comment: What errors did you get when you tried to install adsk?

Comment: @RobStreeting Second one in the image.

Comment: I can't find that module on [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/search/?q=adsk), is the module on github?

Comment: @I think that its a function (third image).

Comment: Aha ok, if you have the module installed already you need to add that directory to your PYTHONPATH environment variable. Follow the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/1506086) to add PYTHONPATH to your environment variables, but also include the full path to the "defs" directory you screenshotted above. Then, reset your terminal and try again.

Comment: @Rob Steeting I have tried it, but its same as before.

Answer (score 2):

1) As it described [here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/fusion360/ENU/?guid=GUID-9701BBA7-EC0E-4016-A9C8-964AA4838954)
it may be required to call from `Tools` Panel of Fusion.

2) Can you try to copy your `adsk` folder to `C:\your_path_to_python_folder\Lib\site-packages\`?

I think, in your case (based on screenshot, you published in post), just copy `C:\Users\Wr\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\Autodesk Fusion 360\API\Python\defs\adsk` as `C:\Python3.7\Lib\site-packages\adsk` or `C:\Users\Wr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\adsk`

3) Otherwise, try to add as PYTHONPATH environment variable location of `%AppData%\Roaming\Autodesk\Autodesk Fusion 360\API\Python` or `C:\Users\Wr\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\Autodesk Fusion 360\API\Python`

4) Otherwise: It may need to launch scripts from certain "environment" via terminal as is described [here](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/manufacturing/2016/03/fusion-360-install-3rd-modules-of-python.html)

In your case, probably:

```
cd "%AppData%\Roaming\Autodesk\Autodesk Fusion 360\API\Python"
# or
# cd "C:\Users\Wr\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\Autodesk Fusion 360\API\Python"
.\python.exe "_here_is_address_to_your_script.py"
```

P.S. I can't comment, thus published as an answer.